# Incrementar fecha en php

Tags: php, mysql, php7, php5

Buenas tardes tengo un for en php que me recorre los días que ingreso un usuario, necesito aumentar la fecha de inicio, cuando por ejemplo selecciono 30 de septiembre y 1 de octubre la fecha del 1 de septiembre me la guarda bien en la base de datos, pero la del 1 de octubre me la pone en ceros.
esto es lo que he intentado.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $dias; $i++) {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO SocioInvitado (IDSocio,IDClub,NumeroDocumento,Nombre,FechaIngreso,Estado,Observaciones,UsuarioTrCr)
                VALUES('$IDSocio','$IDClub','$NumeroDocumentoInvitado','$NombreVisitante','$FechaDeInicio','P',' Invitacion no residente','$id_evento_registro')";
                    $dbo->query($sql);
                    $FechaDeInicio = strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($FechaDeInicio));
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví de la siguiente forma, sumando en formato date.

```
$FechaDeInicio = date("y-m-d", strtotime($FechaDeInicio . "+ 1 days"));
```